# Taylor expansion for Logistic function near a point different than zero

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

How to derive Taylor series expansion for Logistic function near a point $x=a\neq0$ of the form:

$$L(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-k(x-x_0)}}$$

**Edit**

Using the general form for Taylor series coefficients
$c_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}$

I couldn't find a general form for the derivative of L, because each derivative degree has it's own formula.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I've started with Taylor's expansion for $\frac{1}{1+x}$, and tried to replace the variable x by the expansion for $e^x$. but I've ended up with a complex form which I've failed to simplify

Comment: When providing clarification, please click on the tiny `edit` and improve the **body of the post** instead of commenting.

Comment: @Lio: I'm not sure about your question. You want the Taylor series expansion of $L(x)$ at the general point $x=a\neq 0$, but several lines below you mention the Taylor series coefficient at $x=x_0$. If the expansion at $x=x_0$ is sufficient for you then you can rewrite the logistic function as $$L(x)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left [1+\tanh(k(x-x_0)/2)\right ].$$This could be the way since the Taylor expansion of $\tanh(x-x_0)$ at $x=x_0$ is known.

Comment: @MarianG. Thank you very much for the hint, and sorry for the unclear my question, I'm not a math specialist. but I need more one explanation, giving Taylor expansion near x = 0, say f(x); is it correct to say that Taylor expansion near any point x = a is equivalent to f(x - a)? i.e to make a translation x' = x - a.

Comment: @Lio: Not sure if I understand your question correctly. Anyway, assuming that the Taylor expansion of the function $f(x)$ at $x=0$ is known (i.e., we know the coefficients $c_n$ of this expansion) we can state that the coefficients $C_n$ of the Taylor expansion of the function $f(x-a)$ at $x=a$ are the same, i.e. $c_n=C_n$ for every non-negative integer $n$. Hence a kind of _translation_ can be considered.

Comment: @MarianG. Thanks a lot